# Number of elements in equivalence classes of factor groups and sets

Tags: group-theory, equivalence-relations

Are the following statements true or false?

1. Let $M$ be a set and $\sim$ be an equivalence relation in $M$. Then every equivalence class has the same number of elements.
2. Let $(G, \circ)$ be a group and $H \subset G$ a subgroup. Then every equivalence class in the factor group $G/H$ has the same number of elements.

For 1. I suppose it is false, since if we let $M=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{2,3\}\}$ and $\sim$ is "having the same number of elements". Then $|[\{1\}]|=2$, but $|[\{2,3\}]|=1$. Is this right?

For 2. I have a strong feeling that it is true, however I am unable to prove it. Any hints welcome.

Comment: Hint for 2.: for $g \in G$, can you build a bijection between $H$ and the class $gH = \{gh : h \in H\}$?

Comment: Of course $M$ is a finite set and $(G,\circ)$ is a finite group. Note that if you are successful in proving 2°), you will get the famous Lagrange theorem which asserts that the cardinal (= number of elements) of any subgroup of a finite group divides the cardinal of the group itself.

Comment: $\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}$For (1) you are right, but you may make things simpler by building directly the partition, and recovering from it the equivalence relation. So for instance the partition $\mathfrak{P} = \Set{ \Set{1}, \Set{2, 3}}$ of $A = \Set{1, 2, 3}$ yields the equivalence relation on $A$ given by $a \sim b$ iff there is $P \in \mathfrak{P} $ such that $a, b \in P$, whose equivalence classes are precisely the elements of $\mathfrak{P}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right about (1). A more illustrative partition would be, as pointed  out in the comments, $\mathfrak{P}=\{\{[1]_3\}, \{[2]_3,[3]_3\}\}$ of $\Bbb Z_3$.

For (2), consider the bijection $\lambda_g:H\to gH$ given by $\lambda_g(h)=gh$.